# Trouble with passing arguments

Tags: java

I have re-written the code to contain ONLY what I need to know. The code compiles successfully.

I have 2 classes: `Others.java` and `Parameters.java`.

- `Others.java` has 2 functions  `sum()` and `manhrs(int x)`.
- `Parameters.java` has the `main()` method.

I would like to print the value of `int x` rather that `int y`. I have give the code below:

**Parameters.java**

```
package parameters;

public class Parameters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y = 50;
        Others o = new Others();
        //o.manhrs(x); 
        o.manhrs(y); // my output shoud be 100 (form the sum() class), but when I do not know how to do it.
    }
}
```

**Others.java**

```
package parameters;

public class Others {

    public void sum() {
        int x = 100; 
        manhrs(x);
    }

    public void manhrs(int x) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

> Please refer the code too.

Comment: *Hint:* If a method needs a value, and it cannot be passed as a parameter, then method might get the value from a *field*. You have learned about *fields* aka *instance variables*, right?

Comment: One thing you can do: overload the `manhrs()`.

Comment: "Others.java has 2 classes " how could be it possible

Answer (score 1):

> Now I need to call the method manhrs (float x) from main(), but I do not want to pass any arguments here. I simply want to call the method

This is not possible because `manhrs()` requires a parameter of type float. You cannot call this method without any parameters.

I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a pencil and paper. First, write a description of the problem you are trying to solve. Then write the steps needed to solve the problem. Both of these should be in **plain English** (or whatever natural language you are most comfortable with). Describing a solution in words is a key skill which you need to learn if you want to become a good programmer. After you do this exercise, then you can with on translating your plain description into Java.

**Additional thoughts and suggestions**

It appears that there are several issues with your code design so far. Each method is trying to accomplish multiple tasks. For example, `manhrs()` executes a SQL query **and** prints a number. Instead, you need to clearly define each method to do exactly one thing and do it well. You really need two different methods. The fact that you want to call the same method two different ways only further emphasizes that you need **two** methods.

Comment: I did, and now I have clearly defined my problem. Could you go through it please?

Comment: @XSufferingBro Your question still does not describe the problem you are trying to solve. What is the purpose of this program?

Answer (score 0):

> my output shoud be 100(form the sum() class),

Why should it be that? You're clearly passing 50 as the value, which gets printed.

First, `sum ()` is a method. Secondly, if you called it instead of `o.manhrs(y)`, it would output 100

**originally posted**

> Now I need to call the method manhrs(float x) from main(), but I do not want to pass any arguments here

That doesn't make sense

You don't want to pass parameters? Then remove the parameter

```
public void manhrs()
```

You don't do anything but print `x`... Not really clear where `Recipe_Name` came from, but I strongly suggest you read up on SQL injection when you get a chance

---

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to return the SQL results.

Something  like this

```
public float sum(String q) {

    Calculation c = new Calculation();
    float sum = 0;
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = mycon.prepareStatement(q);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        sum = rs.getFloat(1);
   } catch (SQLException e) {

    } 
    return sum;
}
```

Then call the sum method and actually get the sum

```
private String Recipe_Name = "Some name" ;

public void manhrs() {
    DataHandler d = new DataHandler();

    // Beware SQL Injection!! 
    String q ="SELECT SUM(`Man HR`) FROM `process` GROUP BY `Recipe Name`= '"+Recipe_Name+"'";

    // You should really pass the recipe name as the parameter, not the whole query 
    float x = d.sum(q);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Note, `manhrs` could be static in this connect

Comment: I have redid the code to include only what I need. Could you please go through it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting now... You never called `sum()` at all

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can print the value of int x which is in Others() class via the main() method?

Comment: I already told you. `o.sum()`...the x variable is only local to that method, not part of the class

Comment: I think you are confused that the names of parameters mean nothing. `manhrs(int x)` is a completely different `x` than `int x = 100`